# Display TODO/FIXME report in Matlab's command window

Tags: matlab, command, window, report, todo

Using the command

```
checkcode('function.m')
```

you can run the code analyzer on an m-file and output the report in the command window.
Is there any way to do this for TODO/FIXME reports? (without having to cd to the folder that contains the function and manually run it on the whole directory)

Bonus: If so, is it also possible to create custom tags? In eclipse, you can create custom TODO tags like "MTODO" and "JTODO" for different purposes/different people and have them displayed separately. Is this possible in Matlab?
Thanks in advance for any help! I will be continuing my google searches and will post the results if I find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the internal function `dofixrpt`. This returns the HTML displayed in the report, rather than displaying the information at the command line, however.

```
% Run the report and show it
cd('myfolder')
dofixrpt;

% Alternatively, get the HTML of the report directly
html = dofixrpt;

% Write the HTML to a file
filename = tempname;
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s', html);
fclose(fid);

% View the HTML file
web(filename)
```

Type `which dofixrpt` or `edit dofixrpt` to see more details about what it does (it's basically a regular expression search for `%.*TODO` and `%.*FIXME`).

In the HTML report, you can find markers other than TODO and FIXME by specifying a custom marker (the default is NOTE). Unfortunately you can specify only one. If you're up to looking within `dofixrpt` and modifying it very slightly though, it would be very easy to make it look for more.

Finally you could also put in an enhancement request with MathWorks to provide a command similar to `checkcode` that will just do this for you and return the results at the command line. It seems like that would be very easy for them to do, and I'm surprised they haven't already done it, given that they've done something similar for `helprpt`, `coveragerpt`, `deprpt` etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you!
I will have to dig into the code for a bit, but I think dofixrpt has enough material for what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own code checker that calls `checkcode` on every m file in the specified folders.

```
fld_list = {pwd, 'folder', 'other_folder'};
nProblems = 0;

for iFld = 1:length(fld_list)
%     fprintf('Checking %s...\n', fld_list{n});
    files = dir(fullfile(fld_list{iFld}, '*.m'));
    for f = 1:length(files)
        filename = fullfile(fld_list{iFld}, files(f).name);
        customCodeCheck(filename); %custom function
        % check code analyzer
        codeWarnings  = checkcode(filename);
        if not(isempty(codeWarnings))
            fprintf('Problem found in %s\n', files(f).name);
            for iData = 1:length(codeWarnings)
            nProblems = nProblems + 1;
            % print out link to problem
            fprintf('<a href="matlab:opentoline(''%s'',%d)">line %d:</a> %s\n', ...
                filename, ...
                codeWarnings(iData).line, codeWarnings(iData).line, ...
                codeWarnings(iData).message);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You can add to this a `customCodeCheck` function that searches for TODO and FIXME and alerts you to their existence

```
function customCodeCheck(filename)
    fileContents = fileread(filename);
    toDos = strfind(fileContents, 'TODO');
    fixMes = strfind(fileContents, 'FIXME');
    % do other stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This will definitely help me out.